# JBoss EAP 7.0 check startup

Tags: jboss, jboss-eap-7, jboss-cli

I want to check whether my JBoss EAP 7 is started via `jboss-cli`.

With JBoss EAP 6 I could use the following command

```
jboss-cli.bat -c --commands="read-attribute server-state"
```

While the server is starting, the response is `starting`. When the server booted successfully, the response is `running`.

After migrating to JBoss EAP 7.0, the same command returns the following message, while the server is starting. `Failed to connect to the controller: Timeout waiting for the system to boot.` When the server started successfully, the usual message `running` is returned.

My question is: Why can't the `jboss-cli` connect to the server until it started?

Comment: That likely means the management interface is not yet up and listening. It might work if you change the `<command-timeout/>` in the `$JBOSS_HOME/bin/jboss-cli.sh`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In EAP 7.x and EAP 6.3.0 or later, you can configure `jboss.as.management.blocking.timeout` system property to tune timeout (seconds) waiting for service container stability.
Try setting this parameter once connected via CLI.

Since EAP 6.3.0.ER8 there is a new class in jboss.as.controller: BlockingTimeout. This class loads the value of system property jboss.as.management.blocking.timeout or defaults to 300 (seconds).
`Note: This property is not a timeout per deployment but a timeout on container stability and if jboss.as.management.blocking.timeout is reached during startup then all applications will be undeployed and the container shutdown. The reasoning behind this is that having a half-working server is potentially dangerous as you may not notice major failures.`
Thus if your application is unable to load within the given timeout value,CLI will throw the error`Failed to connect to the controller: Timeout waiting for the system to boot`

`jboss-cli.sh --connect --controller=IP:PORT --timeout=40000` configure timeouts value to be more then the amount of time your server takes to start.

Comment: Funny thing is, I haven't set `jboss.as.management.blocking.timeout`, but the Timeout occurs after roughly 2 seconds. After about a minute the server deployed all applications correctly and the CLI works properly.

Comment: You can try by setting this system property via-CLI restart server:  `/system-property=jboss.as.management.blocking.timeout:add(value=600)` and check if it changes anything

Comment: I tried that, but nothing changes. The server started in 34688ms

Comment: That means issue is just with CLI,we can roll out EAP deployment delay now.Try using  `jboss-cli.sh --connect --controller=10.10.10.10:9999 --timeout=40000`,this should work,just add your EAP port,IP properly.

Comment: Sorry, somehow I did not see the notification. With `--timeout=40000` the cli waits until the server is running, which kind of resolves the issue. Nontheless I wonder why the `starting` message did vanish?

Comment: Hi @SilverNak, did you find another solution than setting the `timeout` parameter?

Comment: @Janfy I kind of worked around that issue by not checking for `started` but for `Failed to connect ` and retrying.

Answer (score 0):

Actual command line is 
./jboss-cli.sh --connect command=":read-attribute(name=server-state)"